# How to prevent fluent resource leak warnings in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, warnings, resource-leak

Is there a way to avoid "Potential Resource Leak" warnings for fluent-style method chaining on `AutoCloseable` types? The example below has a warning on each method call.

I would rather not use `@SuppressWarnings`, as it would be needed everywhere the class is used. And I don't want to turn off the warning, as I have found many real bugs with it in the past.

With the latest 2020-03 eclipse it seems the number of false positives has greatly increased, to the point the warning is almost unusable.

```java
public class NoLeak implements AutoCloseable {

    public NoLeak a() {
        return this;
    }

    public NoLeak b() {
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (NoLeak noLeak = new NoLeak()) {
            noLeak
                .a()  // warning here,
                .b()  // here,
                .a(); // and here
        }
    }
}
```

Eclipse 2020-03 (4.15.0), Java 12

Comment: Also a problem for any method returning an already-managed closable resource, for example: `java.nio.file.Path.getFileSystem()`

Comment: Perhaps an annotation on each method that returns an already-managed resource, to indicate callers do not have the responsibility to close it?